# Selecting Id's of Multi-Select Dropdownlist using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How to retreive Id's of selected Books using jQuery ?

Dropdownlist:

```
<select class="form-control" id="books_ids" multiple="true" name="Books"> 
   <option value="">Select Books</option>
   <option value="1">C# In Depth</option>
   <option value="2">C# CLR</option>
   <option value="3">C# Beginner Guide</option>
   <option value="4">Head First C#</option>
   <option value="5">jQuery In Action</option>
   <option value="8">jQuery Head First</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code: (That i tried but it can't retrieved id's as expected) ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        debugger
        var booksIds = [];
        jQuery("#btn_Test").on("click", function () {
            jQuery("#books_ids option:selected").each(function(index,element) {
               booksIds.push(element);
            })
            debugger
            console.log(booksIds)
        })
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Taplar ): sorry for it...it was mistaken during writing question...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dhqk1nuL/  This logic appears to work.  It's pushing the options to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `.val()` function on a multi-select select element will return an array of the selected values:

`var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();`

and in your html:

```
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

You can also use `.text()` to get the text values.

Here's a little codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVqZJq?editors=1111

Comment: I tried that before as well but the val() gives me only one id...instead of expecting multiple id's

Comment: I want to retrieve those ids which is selected from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Are you doing `JQuery("#books_ids").val()` ?

Comment: I made a little codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVqZJq?editors=1111

Comment: If you select multiple and click the button, they get logged to the console